# cx_freeze not working with pyHooks

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pyhook

I am very new to cx_Freeze, but when I tried to use pyHooks, it didn't work.
here's my setup.py code:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includes=["re", "pyHook"]

exe = Executable(
script="hello.py",
base="Win32Gui",
targetName = "hello.exe"
)

setup(
name = "hello",
version = "1",
description = "description",
options = {"build_exe": {"includes":includes}},
executables = [exe]
)
```

and when I run the exe file, the error says:

ImportError: cannot import name cpyHook

Comment: Can you show the output from when you freeze it? It will be quite long, so put it in a pastebin.

Comment: never mind, I fixed it by putting the pyHook folder in the same folder as the exe file.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what you did? When I freeze my app with cxFreeze I have pyHook folder in the same folder as exe. It even has _cpyHook.pyd file in it. But I still get the same error as you.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so one workaround is to manually include `cpyHook.py`.

```
options = {"build_exe": {"includes":includes, 'include_files': ['cpyHook.py']}},
```

You can get `cpyHook.py` in `<python install dir>\Lib\site-packages\pyHook\`